# how to do simple GET REST HTTP REQUEST Wrapped in a calss in Android?

Tags: android, http

i know there are tons of threads about this
but ever since Apache got desperate in SDK 23 and above
90% of them are not valid anymore.

i thought since so many people are doing this in almost any app,

can someone have an example here on how to do a simple HTTP GET call and HTTP POST call in SDK above 23 ?

and even better if it's wrapped in a separate class i can open and always call to it from different screens ?

Comment: You can use Volley or Retrofit library to do HTTP REQUEST .

Comment: yea but this will make it on the main thread,i'm looking for a way to do it on a separate thread.

Comment: @user2560571 retrofit works in separate thread and it notifiy you when it finish using a callback

Comment: that's really nice, do you have an example or a guide on how to use it ?

Comment: @user2560571 Both Volley and Retrofit run on a separate thread .

Answer (score 2):

You can use Retrofit. It will do your work with just one like of code. It also runs the operation on a separate thread. If you want you can also specify to use an OkHttp client if you want.

Here is a link to a tutorial - https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Moreover you can use the various converters available to automatically parse the JSON response output to any of your models. I personally use JacksonConverter but there is a GsonConverter and many others out there.